# When i pressed command + S on macOS, my HTML code changed by VSCode problem

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I created reactjs project and i encountered this problem

before i pressed command + s

[image]

After i pressed command + s

[image]

I tried many different solutions but it was not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you installed an extension to formatting your codes. to disable formatting on save, go to VSCode settings > User tab > Text editor > Formatting. and disable "Format on Save".

### here is a screenshot of that section:

[image]

Comment: It is disabled but the problem is still happening.

Comment: which extensions are installed on your VSCode? Can you name them?

Comment: c/c++, docker, emmet, eslint,

Comment: So I think this is because of eslint json settings file. If you do not use eslint, then uninstall it. if not, you can go to " VSCode settings > User tab > Extensions > Eslint " and edit the settings. (Settings is a json file)

Comment: @Burak-Akgün, If your issue is resolved then I invite you to accept my answer, and if it was helpful (sounds like it was) then please also remember to upvote it as well (if you haven't already). Cheers